# Please help with basic modeling problem (Precalculus)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let's say a particle is going around a circle periodically with constant angular speed and its distance from a line parallel to a diameter of the circle is given by function $f$.

Two points:

1. I was wondering why the graph of this function is given by a function like this (correct answer according to the textbook):

[image]

and not like this:

[image]

2. Why is the correct graph everywhere concave down (for each period), even though the distance from the line increases incrementally for the first $\frac{1}{4}$ of the circle?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The distance varies smoothly and non-linearly. The second graph would describe the motion of a particle that is moving away from the line along a line perpendicular to the line and then gets a certain distance away and abruptly turns around and approaches the line with the same speed.

Comment: @JohnDouma Why is it concave down everywhere in each cycle? thank you.

Comment: You should write the expression for the distance from the line to the point and graph this yourself.

Comment: I did that, but it seems to me that the graph is wrong because I think it should have an inflection point, but it doesn't. That's why I am asking...

Comment: The distance varies directly as $~f(\theta) = \sin(\theta)~$ varies.  As (for example) $~\theta~$ traverses the interval $~0~$ to $~\pi,~$ you have that $~f'(\theta) = \cos(\theta)~$ which is decreasing on this interval.  This explains why the graph is *concave down*.  That is, it is because the first derivative is constantly decreasing.

Comment: It is always concave down exactly because despite describing it as distance from a line *parallel* to a diameter (i.e., *any* line in the plane), the graph is for an actual diameter. Had they chosen a non-diameter, there would be inflection points. The inflection points occur when the particle crosses the diameter parallel to the line. And the sharp angles occur when the particle crosses the line. But when these two are the same, there are no inflection points.